# Android API 15. I have toolbars in my activites but they are not shown in XML

Tags: android, colors, toolbar

Very Novice Android Programmer here. I have this small program where i have my main activity and whenever the user clicks an option, a new activity will open. I am trying to change the color of the top toolbar/actionbar for each different activity. I have tried changing the color through Java code within the activity class in the onCreate() method,

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient));
```

but the program would always crash whenever I would switch to my activity.

I have looked in the XML file of my activity and the toolbar/action code does not show up anywhere, but it does in my main activity, app_bar_main.xml. I'm wondering why the actionbar shows up in activies if it does not show up in the XML file for the activity. How to change the color of the actionbar for newely added non main activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using app theme with action bar. In `res/styles.xml` change your theme to `NoActionBar` version:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Now ActionBar shouldn't be visible. Add your Toolbar XML code to other activity layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work:

ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));

Comment: I have tried this for my main and my other activites and it does not work.

Comment: For some reason this worked...getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.green)); but it says i need API 21